# Create sets in perl

Tags: perl, set, hash

I'm trying to look for sets in three input conditions (See diagram attached).

For example:

**C1**:

```
I
want
to
create
a
set
in
perl
with
some
values
```

**C2**:

```
how
to
create
set
these
values
```

**C3**:

```
a
set
in
perl
with
values
like
these
```

Would yield a set diagram something like this:

[image]

I know how I can do this in a clunky way for each condition:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $C1, '<', 'C1.txt';
open my $C2, '<', 'C2.txt';
open my $C3, '<', 'C3.txt';

my (%c1_vals, %c2_vals, %c3_vals);
$c1_vals{$_}++ while(<$C1>);
$c2_vals{$_}++ while(<$C2>);
$c3_vals{$_}++ while(<$C3>);


my $c1_c2_count = 0;
my $c1_c3_count = 0;
my $c1 = 0;
my $total = 0;
my $all = 0;

for my $val (keys %c1_vals){
    $total++;
    $c1++ if not $c2_vals{$val} and not $c3_vals{$val};
    $c1_c2_count++ if $c2_vals{$val} and not $c3_vals{$val};
    $c1_c3_count++ if $c3_vals{$val} and not $c2_vals{$val};
    $all++ if $c2_vals{$val} and $c3_vals{$val};
}
print "c1 total = $total\n";
print "c1 = $c1\n";
print "c1 + c2  = $c1_c2_count\n";
print "c1 + c3 = $c1_c3_count\n";
print "c1+c2+c3 = $all\n";
```

---

```
c1 total = 11
c1 = 4
c1 + c2  = 2
c1 + c3 = 4
c1+c2+c3 = 1
```

---

But I wanted to know if there's an easier way of doing this using a subroutine that reads each file from `@ARGV` and calculates each set in one.

I've got this far, but can't think of an elegant way of doing this:

```
parse($_) foreach @ARGV;

my %total;

sub parse {
    my $file = shift;
    open my $list, '<', $file or die "Can't read file '$file' [$!]\n";
    while (<$list>) {
        chomp;
        $total{$_}++;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Just for clarity, I want to find all intersections (all numbers in Venn diagram) for all 3 data sets (7 in total). I don't want to use a module, as I want to be a blue to build this into a larger program without too many changes.

Comment: There are a whole host of CPAN modules for manipulating sets, like [`Set::Scalar`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Scalar). Why don't you use one of them?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  I don't want to use a module, as I want to be a blue to build this into a larger program without too many changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program does what I need it to do.

It reads in lists from `@ARGV` and prints out all 5 intersections for a given set. If run as `perl set.pl c1 c2 c3`, and user enters `c1` as the 'primary' set, the sets are defined as follows:

**SetA**: C1

**SetB**: C1 + C2

**SetC**: C1 + C3

**SetD**: C1 + C2 + C3

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

unless ($#ARGV == 2) {
    usage();
    exit;
}

print "Enter primary set: ";
chomp(my $set = <STDIN>);

my (%c1_vals, %c2_vals, %c3_vals);

my $count = 0;
my $c;
my ($c1, $c2, $c3);

parse($_) foreach @ARGV;

my $c1_c2_count = 0;
my $c1_c3_count = 0;
my $cond1 = 0;
my $total = 0;
my $all = 0;

for my $item (keys %c1_vals){                       
    $total++;
    if (not $c2_vals{$item} and not $c3_vals{$item}){
        $cond1++;
    }
    if ($c2_vals{$item} and not $c3_vals{$item}){
        $c1_c2_count++;
    }
    if ($c3_vals{$item} and not $c2_vals{$item}){
        $c1_c3_count++;
    }
    if ($c2_vals{$item} and $c3_vals{$item}){
        $all++;
    }
}

# print numbers for each set
print "$c1 total = $total\n";
print "$c1 = $cond1\n";
print "$c1 + $c2  = $c1_c2_count\n";
print "$c1 + $c3 = $c1_c3_count\n";
print "$c1+$c2+$c3 = $all\n";
my $check = ($cond1 + $c1_c2_count + $c1_c3_count + $all);
print "check = $check\n";


# read in each file. $ARGV[0] is set as the 'primary' set (ie that for which intersecting lists are found)
sub parse {
    $count++;
    my $file = shift;
    ($c = $file) =~ s/\.[^.]+$//;
    open my $list, '<', $file or die "Can't read file '$file' [$!]\n";
    while(<$list>) {
        chomp;
        if ($count == 1){
            my @split = split(/\t/);
            $c1_vals{$split[0]}++;
             $c1 = $c;
         }
        if ($count == 2){
            my @split = split(/\t/);
            $c2_vals{$split[0]}++;
             $c2 = $c;
         }
        if ($count == 3){
            my @split = split(/\t/);
            $c3_vals{$split[0]}++;
             $c3 = $c;
         }
    }
}

sub usage {
    print "Usage: set.pl <list1> <list2> <ist3>\n";
    print "Calculates intersections between different sets\n";
}
```

When run as `perl set.pl c1.txt c2.txt c3.txt` this yields:

```
Enter primary set: c1

c1 total = 11
c1 = 3
c1 + c2  = 2
c1 + c3 = 4
c1+c2+c3 = 2
check = 11
```

Answer (score 2):

So long as you keep it under 32-64 sets, this is probably easier with bitwise arithmetic:

```
my %c_vals;
$c_vals{$_} |= 1 while(<$C1>);
$c_vals{$_} |= 2 while(<$C2>);
$c_vals{$_} |= 4 while(<$C3>);

my $total = values %c_vals;
my $c1 = grep { $_ & 1 } values %c_vals;
my $c1_c2_count = grep { ($_ & 3) == 3 } values %c_vals;
my $c1_c3_count = grep { ($_ & 5) == 5 } values %c_vals;
my $all = grep { $_ == 7 } values %c_vals;

print "c1 total = $total\n";
print "c1 = $c1\n";
print "c1 + c2  = $c1_c2_count\n";
print "c1 + c3 = $c1_c3_count\n";
print "c1+c2+c3 = $all\n";

...

my @count_in_set;
foreach my $val (values %c_values) {
    $count_in_set[$val]++;
}
for (my $i=1; $i<=7; $i++) {
    printf "Count in set %03b: %d\n", $i, $count_in_set[$i];
}
```

---

In the general case:

```
my %vals;
my $n = 0;
foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    $vals{$_} |= 1 << $n for <$fh>;
    $n++;
}
my @count_in_set;
foreach my $val (values %c_values) {
    $count_in_set[$val]++;
}
for (my $i=1; $i<=$#count_in_set; $i++) {
    printf "Count in set %0*b: %d\n", $n, $i, $count_in_set[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cpan module [List::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Compare) provides a handy api for n-list operations including list intersections.

As far as consuming the files, File::Slurp provides an easy api for getting array refs, the complete example would be

```
use List::Compare;
use File::Slurp;
my @lists = ();

push(@lists, read_file( $_, array_ref => 1 ) )  foreach @ARGV;

my @intersection = List::Compare->new(@lists)->get_intersection();

print join('', @intersection);
```

example usage `intersection.pl l1.txt l2.txt l3.txt`

Which outputs

```
set
values
```

Comment: But I want to find all intersections (see Venn), not just those values shared by all